# How to use tabular amplitude data in Abaqus BC using Python scripts?

Tags: python, scripting, abaqus, finite-element-analysis, amplitude

I have a long set of tabular data which I need to use as amplitude in Abaqus, using the script.

Using scripts, normally I can enter a tabular amplitude as :

```
myModel.TabularAmplitude(name='x_2p1_10_3p2s',timeSpan=STEP,smooth=SOLVER_DEFAULT,data=((0.0, 0.0), (0.01, 1.0), (0.015, 1.0)))
```

Here, there are 3 rows of data. Suppose my data is of 200 rows, it is not possible to enter it manually, how to do it? I need to use this amplitude in assigning future boundary conditions in the model.

Comment: where is the data, in a file or something? The result of some calculation? Its not clear what you want to do.

Comment: They are in a text file in the form of rows and columns. They can be transferred to an excel as well. The data given in the bit of code here has 3 rows and 2 columns. Since the volume is less, it can be typed into the specific format. 

Suppose I have a tabular form of data which has 200 rows and is 2 columns long. How to read that in here using the same syntax as used in this code bit?

Comment: this is quite basic python `open` , `readlines` , etc. Google search there are tons of python tutorials out there.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the input. I know that we can read excel using pandas or similar modules. Or maybe read normal text files into python by open and readlines. But they are not working in the Abaqus scripts. So I was wondering if there was any other way.

Comment: show the code you have tried . No need to use excel as an intermediate step, python can read text files just fine.